# D3 force layout using canvas zoom

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, force-layout

i have basic d3 force layout, but for rendering edges and nodes I´m using canvas. What I need is to set up zoom behaviour.

When I implemented zoom, like on example below, zoom works only after d3 layout animation is stopped. When I´m draging nodes zoom don´t work too.

Here is my draw method, which I call onTick event:

```
             function drawCanvas() {

                context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

                edges.forEach(function (d) {
                    // Draw a line from source to target.
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
                    context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
                    context.stroke();
                });

            }
```

I also registered zoom event which fire this method:

```
            function onZoomChanged() {
                context.save();
                context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                context.scale(d3.event.scale, d3.event.scale);
                context.translate(d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[1]);
                drawCanvas();
                context.restore();


                container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }
```

Like I mentioned, zoom works only if layout is stoped and nodes are not moving. It is possible to get it work ALL TIME, when layout is still procesing ?

Taknks for help!

I create basic example of my problem on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg0jwtnn/). Zoom work after while..

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you unable to move objects while zoomed or can't u zoom while objects are being rendered?

Comment: Like you said, zoom is not possible while objects are being rendered... After layout stop calculated positions of nodes => nodes are not moving => zoom start works good

Comment: The only solution I can think of is that you handle the rendering on a buffer canvas and continously show snapshots of that one on your main canvas while also scaling your main canvas according to your zooming commands.

Comment: Thnaks. Please can you do it in raw code example ? I can also prepare some jsfidlle for example. Update, i try implement your suggestion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8903dca/) I have two canvas, but still the same bug..

Comment: I see another problem as well, which you need to solve first. The zoom-function includes the draw-function. What you want to have is the `context.scale()` and `context.translate()` inside the draw-function, always. Then you want to change the scale and translate parameters in your zoom-function. I'll have to get back to you in a few hours, then I can give you a more proper answer.

Comment: I updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg0jwtnn/1/), now is something happening when I zoom but is not work correctly, node is smaller and smaller unitl it fully disappear. I Will be waiting for help, thank you for your time !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73258/discussion-between-niddro-and-martin-hascak).